# Outlook Express gives the error "This folder is in use"

Tags: windows-xp, outlook-express

Every time I exit Outlook Express on Windows XP, it shows:

> This folder in use by Outlook Express or another program` (in Russian).

It gives this error on *every* application closing, when it compresses the base. I have rebooted, and there is enough disk space. **What is causing this error?**

Answer (score 0):

You have the auto-compact function selected which automatically compacts the databases under certain circumstances. Unfortunately, something is blocking it from completing. There is nothing *bad* about this, and you can stop it by turning off the auto-compact setting:

Of course it would be better to figure out why it won’t compact. There are a few reasons this can happen:

- Not enough disk space to create temporary files (must have as much free space as the message store uses)
- The file is actually in use. Look at which folder OE says failed. Then you use [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to confirm that the `.dbx` file is only used by OE and not something else. If so, then you can select (click on) either `Outlook Express` or `Local Folders` before compacting. Try compacting manually (*File⇨Folder⇨Compact (All Folders)*) to reset OE’s compact schedule.
- If you have created a new folder, then restarting OE should fix it.
- If you have subscribed to a bunch of newsgroups, then `folders.dbx` could be broken. Try deleting (or better, renaming) the file. You will lose your newsgroups, but when OE re-creates the file, it should stop giving you compaction errors. Then you can re-subscribe to your newsgroups, but do it one at a time.